# AppCompatActivity attempting to register while current state is RESUMED

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This all works fine from "MainActivity" it's when I try and use it in any other activity that it crashes, I'm 99% it's something to do with 'AppCompatActivity' eg. "this" as an parameter in myreq.openFileRequester(), I'm just not sure how to resolve it, I'm sure it's something pretty simple, the activity 2nd activity has already 'started' or I wouldn't be able to press the button that makes it crash.

2nd Activity.

```
class EditCards : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate( savedInstanceState: Bundle? ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState )
        
        cardIntoText.setOnClickListener {
            myreq.openFileRequester(
                this,
                "*/*"
            ) { a ->
                Log.d(
                    "openFileRequester = $a"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

myreq class;

```
package com.example.cardgamexxx

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.net.Uri
import android.text.InputType
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import com.example.cardgamexxx.RequesterType.InputRequester_Password
import com.example.cardgamexxx.RequesterType.MessageRequester_Ok
import com.example.cardgamexxx.RequesterType.MessageRequester_YesNo
import com.example.cardgamexxx.RequesterType.MessageRequester_YesNoCancel

class Requester {
    
    fun openFileRequester(cActivity: AppCompatActivity,filter : String,callback: (answer: Uri) -> Unit) {
        val openFileRequester = cActivity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri ->
            callback(uri)
        }
        openFileRequester.launch(filter)
    }

    fun pathRequester(cActivity: AppCompatActivity,filter : String,callback: (answer: Uri) -> Unit) {
        val getUserFolderData = cActivity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) { uri: Uri ->
            callback(uri)
        }
        getUserFolderData.launch(filter.toUri())
    }
    
}
```

The Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cardgamexxx, PID: 10319
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.cardgamexxx.EditCards@e70d6c8 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.register(ActivityResultRegistry.java:123)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:659)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:668)
        at com.example.cardgamexxx.Requester.openFileRequester(Requester.kt:91)
        at com.example.cardgamexxx.EditCards.onCreate$lambda-8(EditCards.kt:515)
        at com.example.cardgamexxx.EditCards.$r8$lambda$GOSDQkm1gI3skbMPgXpW80EcH9M(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.cardgamexxx.EditCards$$ExternalSyntheticLambda15.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

MainActivity; as Requested by (Mike.M)

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main Activity
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @RequiresApi(
        Build.VERSION_CODES.R
    )
    
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Application
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        myreq.openFileRequester(this,"*/*") { a ->
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's what you were doing with that. Yeah, you can't really use it that way. The `registerForActivityResult()` calls must be made before the `Activity`'s started; e.g., in field initializers, during `onCreate()`, etc. In your setup, that call isn't happening until well after that, when the user clicks the `View`.

Comment: Did you get a chance to [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register)? It specifically goes over why you cannot use a lambda for Activity Results and why you need to register ahead of time and not immediately before you `launch`.

Comment: @MikeM. :( odd, the MainActivity is started and it works from with in MainActivity but EditCardsActivity though hasn't started it doesn't, so by that logic start the 2nd Activity hidden (or any Activity that might require them).

Comment: @ianhanniballake why? well essentially the finite reason is I didn't want a bunch of messy code, one ring to rule them all one place for it to break and fall, rather than debugging a bunch of copy cat code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes I did read it, I got the basic concept I guess but for a large part but not all when it comes to https://developer.android.com/ it's may as well be speaking Silbo Gomero (spoken on the island of Gomera) probably could have used a better idiom there, I don't know for some reason I read it an I some how feel I have to upgrade my English Language knowledge to something far more out of my class (posh) or the queens English.

Comment: In `MainActivity`, the `myreq.openFileRequester()` call is happening while `onCreate()` runs, which is before `MainActivity` has reached the `STARTED` state. In `EditCards`, however, `myreq.openFileRequester()` isn't called until the user clicks, which can't happen until well after the `Activity` has fully started. Make sense?

Comment: @MikeM. I've posted it in the main post for you, don't ask what this is doing RequiresApi I'm hoping it is ensuring that I'm not using deprecated calls, which by the way would have made this easier with startActivityForResult? or some such, I don't see the point in learning old pre-android 11 stuff, as it's only work I'll end up throwing out, better to start learning Android with what is now and not what is going away.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, it does. thanks.

Comment: @MikeM. wild idea, but could one when OnCreate() is called register them but not launch them and keep a handle around for them, and use the handle.launch() as and when required?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically how they intend for it to be used already. For example, on [that page that Ian linked](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch), the `val getContent` is the handle, and it shows how that's obtained early (in a field initializer, in that example), and then launched later in the click event.

Comment: @MikeM. that's how I've used it elsewhere too before I wrote the openFileRequester() code, I just wanted to use it in a different way other than registering 6 of them, (I'm not expressing myself well, I know and I'm sorry)  when that data returned is commonly if not exclusively a Uri, I then have to handle that data returned and where it goes immediately between { a -> (handle here) }, I'd rather it returned from result = openFileRequester.launch("*/*") within the button listener but that's just not how Android works, thanks for helping me understand though, it is appreciated.

Comment: Nah, you're expressing yourself just fine; at least, I'm fairly certain I understand what you're going for. You're absolutely right, too, in that programming Android simply works differently in many ways. VB6 was one of the first major languages I played with, so I know how it is to want all the other languages to be as straightforward and easy-reading. You'll get used to it after a while, though. :-) Good luck with your project. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake about "why you need to register ahead of time and not immediately before you launch" I still not getting it, can you perhaps clear it more? Is it about performance issue?